# Siddur Ha'Arizal (R' Asher Margaliot)

Tags: prayer-book, chasidut-hasidism, nusach-sefard, arizal, nusach-ari

[This link](http://www.nehora.com/siddur-haarizal-r-asher-margaliot-new-edition/) claims that the Siddur Ha'Arizal compiled by Rabbi Asher Margaliot is the siddur that was used by the Ba'al Shem Tov and his original followers. How accurate is it to say this?

Comment: see [this](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/האר"י#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.93.D7.95.D7.A8_.D7.94.D7.90.D7.A8.22.D7.99)  link in which you can find it and others sidure haari.

Comment: the siddur of the Rabbi Shabtai mirashkov (Sofer of the  Besht)  and siddur Rabbi  Kapil are closest to the Besht

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only on the technical basis that it is according to the nusach of the Ari z'l.

The actual expert sofer of the Ba'al Shem Tov was Rabbi Shabbtai of Rashkov. The siddur which the Ba'al Shem Tov used was written by him. Rabbi Shabbtai was an expert on the nusach of the Ari and all his kavanot. There are still manuscript copies of that siddur in Rabbi Shabbtai's own hand in existence. Printed versions of his siddur with all the kavanot can be purchased today.

Comment: I see. Is there a link where I can view these original manuscripts?

Comment: I don't know about links to view them. But photographs of the manuscripts are included in the printed version of the siddur.

Comment: http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=5993&strReferer=search&PPGR=0

Comment: This is not to be confused with another famous Siddur by a R Shabtai Sofer of Peremyshliany which is one of the earliest printed Nusach Ashkenaz Siddurim.